# Inspect bound events attached to element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I am attempting to inspect the events bound to an element using the following syntax

```
$(item).data("events");
```

I have also tried

```
$(item).data("events").change;
```

I know for certain that the change event is bound and if I do this

```
$(item).attr("change")
```

I can see that an attribute with that name has been registered.

I am using the syntax:

```
$(item).change(handler)
```

to bind an event.

Why can't I get at my data("events") object?

Comment: What happens when you try those things?  Are they empty?

Comment: I don't get an object returned. I get "undefined".  With this, I absolutely made sure I was looking at element I had bound events to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$(item).data` function only lets you have access to certain data, namely data that you put there and not the events that jQuery has bound.

Try:

```
$._data($(item)[0])
```

if `item` is a selector, if it is a reference to a node, the code can be shortened to:

```
$._data(item)
```

I found this via reading [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js). I consider it a debugging tool only.